# rails command does not work. getting error "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I try any rails command, even `rails -v`, I keep getting the error - `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Things I have already tried:

`gem install rails` (successfully installed)

`gem update rails`

`gem update bundler`

tried uninstalling bundler and reinstalling it.

Current ruby -v is: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]`

None of the above worked. Any ideas?

Comment: what does `which bundle` output ?

Comment: the output for which bundle is - `/Users/davidhan/.rbenv/shims/bundle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed rails successfully `rails -v` should work fine. For running `bundle` you have to be in a `Gemfile` directory. Are you sure you are in the root directory of your app? If not cd to your root directory and run the commands

```
$ rails new my_app
$ cd my_app
$ bundle
```

---

**EDIT**
The problem can occur if you have to be logged in as an admin user to run the command but the gemfile was in a directory under a different user.

Comment: I'm sure that I installed rails successfully. `gem update rails` outputs "nothing to update" since I have the latest rails installed. I don't have an app yet, I'm trying to run the rails new command, but any command that starts with rails is not working.

Comment: @dhan hmmm.. starnge. try `gem uninstall rails` and `gem uninstall railties` and then `gem install rails`. Please post what do you see in console when you do this

Comment: `gem uninstall rails`
`Successfully uninstalled rails-5.0.0.1`
`gem uninstall railties`
`Successfully uninstalled railties-5.0.0.1`
`gem install rails`
`2 gems installed`  
@Tony Vincent `rails -v` or `rails new` gives me the same error message that I got originally

Comment: @dhan are you sure you are running the command as the same user? see my edit

Comment: Hm.. If I use sudo before rails new it actually worked.. Not sure why. Thanks for the help!